# How to set maxlength property for lightning-input-field inside lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

For example ZipCode field length in sObject is 10.
how can I set it on the lightning-input-field ?
I saw that on lightning-input I can , but this is not the case I need.

Thx

Comment: Did you check if `data-maxlength` works for you as a custom HTML5 attribute? Oftentimes the `data-<html attr name>` is a way to adjust the attribute hidden within the component.  Inspired by [this blog post](http://www.salesforceevergreen.com/html5-attributes-in-lwc/)

Comment: maxlength attribute is not supported in `lightning-input-field`. You can handle the validation in JS controller with onchange event or on form submit.

Comment: @BrianMiller thanks tried it on the lightning-input-field, it not works too bad.

Comment: @Amol I think that onsubmit is to much for this kind of checks.... I did tried using the onchange event, but I ca't figure out how to prevent the typing after reaching the limit. 
tried event.preventDefaults , return false, nothing works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lightning-input-field` [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/documentation) mentions this:

> If a user enters anything in an input field, you can no longer programmatically set the value of the field. The assumption is that there are unsaved changes that should not be overwritten. If you want to be able to overwrite user changes, you can use lightning-input instead.

So even if you try to trigger `onchange` event on `lightning-input-field` to substring only first 10 char, you will encounter a system exception.

You might want to upvote this related idea about [Remove restriction on programmatically setting lightning-input-fields](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CZPmQAO)

It seems that the only workaround for now is to use `lightning-input` to apply `max-length`